# Arangodb container reaches memory limit and crashes while filtering using 'path' for graph traversal

Tags: docker, graph, traversal, arangodb, aql

**My Environment**

ArangoDB Version: 3.6.2
Storage Engine: RocksDB
Deployment Mode: Single Server
Deployment Strategy: Manual Start in Docker
Infrastructure: Own
Operating System: Linux version 4.4.0-154-generic (gcc version 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) )
Total RAM in your machine: 4GB
Disks in use: HDD
Used Package: Docker-Official Docker library

**My Problem:**
I have a graph with 60k nodes and 4*60k edges. Whenever I try using 'path' for Filter or Return, the memory limit reaches, arangodb container crashes and it gets restarted. However, if I don't use 'path' and use 'vertex' or 'edge' only for filter or return the query executes and produces result as expected. This issue is seen in version 3.6.2.

> However, in arangodb 3.1.18 this issue is not seen and everything is
>   working fine.

**Sample Query:**

```
FOR v, e, p IN 6 OUTBOUND "root_node" GRAPH "my_graph_db"
FILTER (
        LENGTH(p.edges) == 6 && 
        LIKE (p.edges[3]._from,"Data_level_3%",true) && 
        (LIKE (p.edges[3]._to, "Data_level_4%") || LIKE (p.edges[3]._to, "Data_4%"))  && 
        ...................................................................
)

LIMIT 0,10
RETURN { 
      result: Merge(
           {data: v},
           {parent_id: p.edge[5]._id}
      ),
      .................
}
```

**Expected result:**
The arangodb container should not reach memory limit crash. 'Path' attributes needs to accessed while doing queries.

Please refer to https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/11277